# Open Google Chrome on Centos 7 and screenshot it

Tags: linux, centos

I have Centos 7 server installed on AWS and I installed "google-chrome" on it using a sample code on the internet which works fine.

```
cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - \$basearch
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
EOF

yum install google-chrome-stable
```

I got no error message so I believe Chrome is installed. Now I just want to open it passing a URL as a parameter (so when Chrome opens it will open with the URL I gave) and after 5 seconds I want to make a screenshot. I will do this once every hour using a cronjob, so this last part is easy.

I just dont know how to open Google Chrome in my Centos 7 server since it does not have a monitor and I want to know how to screenshot it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to do this with chrome. Instead, curl is the tool you are looking for.

```
curl <website url>:80 (or 443 for https)
```

from there, if you need to check something specific, you can grep out for what you are looking for. Or if you are creating a heath check style and just want to make sure it is up. -I flag will return the header which will contain the HTTP response code.